# When to use torch.no_grad() is safe in forward propagation? Why does it hurt my model badly?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, autograd

I have trained a CNN model whose forward-prop is like:

```
*Part1*: learnable preprocess​
*Part2*: Mixup which does not need to calculate gradient
*Part3*: CNN backbone and classifier head
```

Both *part1* and *part3* need to calculate the gradient and need update weights when back-prop, but *part2* is just a simple mixup and don't need gradient, so I tried wrapped this Mixup with `torch.no_grad()` to save computational resource and speed up training, which it indeed speed my training a lot, but the model`s prediction accuracy drops a lot.

I'm wondering if Mixup does not need to calculate the gradient, why wrap it with `torch.no_grad()` hurt the model`s ability so much, is it due to loss of the learned weights of *Part1*, or something like break the chain between *Part1* and *Part2*?

---

Edit:

Thanks @Ivan for your reply and it sounds reasonable, I also have the same thought but don't know how to prove it.

In my experiment when I apply `torch.no_grad()` on *Part2*, the GPU memory consumption drops a lot, and training is much faster, so I guess this *Part2* still needs gradient even it does not have learnable parameters.

So can we conclude that `torch.no_grad()` should not be applied between 2 or more learnable blocks, otherwise it would drop the learning ability of blocks before this `no_grad()` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but *part2* is just simple mixup and don't need gradient

It actually does! In order to compute the gradient flow and backpropagate successfully to *part1* of your model (which is learnable, according to you) you need to compute the gradients on *part2* as well. Even though there are no learnable parameters on *part2* of your model.

What I'm assuming happened when you applied `torch.no_grad()` on *part2* is that only *part3* of your model was able to learn while *part1* stayed untouched.

---

*Edit*

> So can we conclude that torch.no_grad() should not be applied between 2 or more learnable blocks, otherwise it would drop the learning ability of blocks before this no_grad() part?

The reasoning is simple: to compute the gradient on part1 you need to compute the gradient on intermediate results, irrespective of the fact that you won't use those gradients to update the tensors on part2. So indeed, you are correct.